# how to get screenshot of a web page

Tags: php, silverlight, screenshot

I have a website running on my own server, using PHP and Sliverlight.
I want to implement a function that when a user click a button, the server takes a screenshot of the page and saves the picture on the server. Note that user behavior will change the page.

I wonder how to solve this using php and javascript? Does wkhtmltopdf managr it ? Any idea is appreciate.

Comment: Please, look around for duplicates. [This question explains how to take a screenshot with silverlight controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673842/taking-screenshot-of-web-page-with-silverlight-controls-programatically), that should help you on your way (BTW: browser JS doesn't have access to the file system of the client)

Comment: Thank you. But I may not be able to access the silverlight codes.